# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

```
   (function( $ ) {
     $(document).ready( function(){
       $('form.wpcf7-form input').each(function(){
         //or you could also do this which is even less maintenance
         var name = $(this).attr('name').substring(0, 10);
         var type = $(this).attr('type');
         switch(type){
           case 'radio':
            case 'checkbox': 
             name += '-'+$(this).attr('value');
         }
         $(this).attr('class',name);
       });
     });
   })( jQuery );
```

I try to cut the class name but I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined` error.

Can some one help me get this error fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: That means that `$(this).attr('name')` is either undefined (or null) or is not a string. The related HTML would be quite helpful.

Comment: Troubleshooting Tip: Which line is causing the problem? Your console will tell you.  Next tip: simplify.  What is the value of `$(this).attr('name')`? (Hint: It's undefined, which is why you're getting the error).

Comment: please post your html dom

Comment: Well it appears that not all your inputs have names. So maybe you should check to make sure it has a name before you process it.

Comment: If you want to cut `class` name then why you are using `$(this).attr('name')`. Use `$(this).attr('class')` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is WordPress, and Contact Form 7, I figure some of the HTML is out of your control.

Adding a class based on the name would give the impression you want to do some styling against those inputs.  Did you know you can style based on the name, without adding classes?  For example, for a text input named "first-name", you could do this in your CSS:

```
input[type="radio"][name="first-name"] {
    border-color: red;
}
```

If that's doesn't satisfy your needs (and to answer the *direct question* you asked) then you'd need to do a conditional so that you don't throw this error:

```
// simplify to a single no-conflict safe document-ready
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    $('form.wpcf7-form input').each( function() {
        if ( $(this).attr('name') ) {   
             var name = $(this).attr('name').substring(0, 10);
             var type = $(this).attr('type');
             switch(type) {
                 case 'radio':
                 case 'checkbox': 
                     name += '-'+$(this).attr('value');
             }

             $(this).attr('class',name);
        }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

As several people have commented, you get the error of undefined, because one of the input elements on you page doesn't have a name attribute. This breaks the script and prevents it from running.

You have to do a conditional check to see if the name attribute is present. Something like this would work:

```
$('form.wpcf7-form input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() { 
    $(this).addClass( ( ( $(this).attr('name') ) ? $(this).attr('name').substring(0, 10) + '-' + $(this).val() : null ) );  
});
```